# How to deploy .net core in Kubernetes?

Tags: .net, linux, docker, kubernetes

Recently I started study Kubernetes. And I want to deploy .net core in Kubernetes.
How to deploy .net core in Kubernetes ? 
Maybe there is a simple example ?

Comment: How much efforts have you given to find the result? You should first find out, if do not get anything help after trying, then in your question description, you need to specify what do you want, you are trying, what have you got, what is expected, what is you question now. So you can follow this.

Comment: You can even google it: 01. https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-istio-aspnetcore-part1, 02. https://www.blexin.com/en-US/Article/Blog/NET-Core-Docker-and-Kubernetes-42, 03. https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/aspnet-core-app-deployment-in-ibm-cloud-kubernetes-service/, 04. https://medium.com/@bterkaly/running-asp-net-applications-in-kubernetes-a-detailed-step-by-step-approach-96c98f273d1a, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of resources on the web for the specific mechanics that I will add at the bottom. This is a very broad question and probably not a correct type of question for SO. However, I am going to try to point you in a good direction.

The first step to deploying a .NET Core application to Kubernetes is to understand how to create a container that runs your .NET Core app. This will typically be using Docker.

Once you have a docker container built using a linux image, you will need to publish that image to a container registry so you can define which registry to pull your image from in your Kubernetes yaml. I would recommend you use something like [minikube](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/learning-environment/minikube/) to do it locally.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/dotnetcore/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/containerized-lifecycle/design-develop-containerized-apps/build-aspnet-core-applications-linux-containers-aks-kubernetes

Answer (score 1):

You might consider using OpenShift (which is a Kubernetes distribution).  Red Hat provides containers with .NET Core ready to go.  It makes things really easy.

Disclaimer: I work for Red Hat.

Answer (score 0):

If someone will be interesting. I resolved my problem.

steps how. Answer this my conception and this is my opinion:

Before your begin

- You need have linux machine and docker and Kubernetes.
- Create Docker Private Registry
- Create Secret on Kubernetes for Docker

Steps for resolve issue.

- You need to install a dotnet
- you need to create project in dotnet
- afrer that will be next step it is create docker file
- and build in docker
- then you need to create tag for your image in Docker
- and deploy to K8s